# How to save results of user input from a dialog box with XFA/Livecycle

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, xfa

I have developed a form in LiveCycle ES4 which I then make an Adobe Reader compatible PDF, and need some help. The first page of the form is essentially a data set which has predetermined fields. On the second page there is a button which takes all of the data entered from the first page and generates a written report based on that data.

However, not all the information needed to generate the report is contained on the first page and it's a standardized data set, so I cannot add additional fields. My solution was to use a pop-up dialog box to collect 4 pieces of information from the user, which uses two dropdown boxes and two free text fields (for now). I used a tool I found online to help me build the dialog box (huge thanks to BR001 for creating it) and now I need to know how to store the user's input as a variable to be used in the same block of code for the 'Generate report' button, where my code generates the written report.

I'm a beginner to JavaScript and thusfar know what I know simply to create this form. How can I accomplish this? Thank you!

Here is my code for the dialog box:

```
    function dialog()
{
    var dialogDescriptor = 
    {
        description:
        {
            name: "dailog1",
            align_children: "align_distribute",
            margin_width: 20,
            margin_height: 20,
            elements: [
                {
                    type: "cluster",
                    item_id: "clu1",
                    align_children: "align_left",
                    alignment: "align_center",
                    name: "Enter location of evaluation:",
                    bold: true,
                    elements: [
                        {
                            type: "view",
                            align_children: "align_distribute",
                            elements: [
                                {
                                    type: "static_text",
                                    alignment: "align_center",
                                    name: "State:",
                                },
                                {
                                    width: 80,
                                    height: 22,
                                    type: "popup",
                                    item_id: "pop1",
                                    alignment: "align_center",
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "static_text",
                                    alignment: "align_center",
                                    name: "County:",
                                },
                                {
                                    width: 125,
                                    height: 22,
                                    type: "popup",
                                    item_id: "pop2",
                                    alignment: "align_center",
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            type: "view",
                            align_children: "align_left",
                            elements: [
                                {
                                    type: "static_text",
                                    name: "Place: (ex: Memorial Hermann Hospital Room 123)",
                                },
                                {
                                    width: 385,
                                    height: 22,
                                    type: "edit_text",
                                    item_id: "edi1",
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    type: "cluster",
                    align_children: "align_distribute",
                    name: "How do you want to refer to the subject?",
                    elements: [
                        {
                            width: 385,
                            height: 22,
                            type: "edit_text",
                            item_id: "edi2",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    type: "ok_cancel",
                    alignment: "align_top",
                    ok_name: "Create Narrative",
                }
            ]
        },
        initialize : function(dialog)
        {
            dialog.load({
                "pop1": dialogObject.pop1,
                "pop2": dialogObject.pop2,
                "edi1": dialogObject.edi1,
                "edi2": dialogObject.edi2,
            });
        },
        validate : function(dialog)
        {
            //add validate code here
            return true;
        },
        commit : function(dialog)
        {
            var elements = dialog.store();
            dialogObject.pop1 = elements["pop1"];
            dialogObject.pop2 = elements["pop2"];
            dialogObject.edi1 = elements["edi1"];
            dialogObject.edi2 = elements["edi2"];
        },
        "clu1" : function(dialog)
        {
        },
        "pop1": function (dialog)
        {
            var lst1 = dialog.store()["pop1"];
            for (var item in lst1)
            {
                if (lst1[item] > 0)
                {
                    var selectedValue = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (selectedValue == "Alabama") {
            dialog.load(
            {
                "pop2": ({"Autauga": 1, "Baldwin": -1, "Barbour": -2, "Bibb": -3, "Blount": -4, "Bullock": -5, "Butler": -6, "Calhoun": -7, "Chambers": -8, "Cherokee": -9, "Chilton": -10, "Choctaw": -11, "Clarke": -12, "Clay": -13, "Cleburne": -14, "Coffee": -15, "Colbert": -16, "Conecuh": -17, "Coosa": -18, "Covington": -19, "Crenshaw": -20, "Cullman": -21, "Dale": -22, "Dallas": -23, "DeKalb": -24, "Elmore": -25, "Escambia": -26, "Etowah": -27, "Fayette": -28, "Franklin": -29, "Geneva": -30, "Greene": -31, "Hale": -32, "Henry": -33, "Houston": -34, "Jackson": -35, "Jefferson": -36, "Lamar": -37, "Lauderdale": -38, "Lawrence": -39, "Lee": -40, "Limestone": -41, "Lowndes": -42, "Macon": -43, "Madison": -44, "Marengo": -45, "Marion": -46, "Marshall": -47, "Mobile": -48, "Monroe": -49, "Montgomery": -50, "Morgan": -51, "Perry": -52, "Pickens": -53, "Pike": -54, "Randolph": -55, "Russell": -56, "St. Clair": -57, "Shelby": -58, "Sumter": -59, "Talladega": -60, "Tallapoosa": -61, "Tuscaloosa": -62, "Walker": -63, "Washington": -64, "Wilcox": -65, "Winston": -66})
            });
            }
            else if (selectedValue == "Alaska") {
            dialog.load(
            {
                "pop2": ({"Aleutians East": 1, "Aleutians West": -1, "Anchorage": -2, "Bethel": -3, "Bristol Bay": -4, "Denali": -5, "Dillingham": -6, "Fairbanks North Star": -7, "Haines": -8, "Juneau": -9, "Kenai Peninsula": -10, "Ketchikan Gateway": -11, "Kodiak Island": -12, "Lake And Peninsula": -13, "Matanuska-Susitna": -14, "Nome": -15, "North Slope": -16, "Northwest Arctic": -17, "Prince of Wales-Outer Ketchikan": -18, "Sitka": -19, "Skagway": -20, "Southeast Fairbanks": -21, "Valdez-Cordova": -22, "Wade Hampton": -23, "Wrangell": -24, "Yakutat": -25})
            });
            }
        },
        "pop2" : function(dialog)
        {
        },
        "edi1" : function(dialog)
        {
        },
        "edi2" : function(dialog)
        {
        },
    };
    var dialogObject = 
    {
        pop1: ({' ':1, Alabama:-1, Alaska:-1, Arizona:-2, Arkansas:-3, California:-4, Colorado:-5, Connecticut:-6, Delaware:-7, Florida:-8, Georgia:-9, Hawaii:-10, Idaho:-11, Illinois:-12, Indiana:-13, Iowa:-14, Kansas:-15, Kentucky:-16, Louisiana:-17, Maine:-18, Maryland:-19, Massachusetts:-20, Michigan:-21, Minnesota:-22, Mississippi:-23, Missouri:-24, Montana:-25, Nebraska:-26, Nevada:-27, 'New Hampshire':-28, 'New Jersey':-29, 'New Mexico':-30, 'New York':-31, 'North Carolina':-32, 'North Dakota':-33, Ohio:-34, Oklahoma:-35, Oregon:-36, Pennsylvania:-37, 'Rhode Island':-38, 'South Carolina':-39, 'South Dakota':-40, Tennessee:-41, Texas:-42, Utah:-43, Vermont:-44, Virginia:-45, Washington:-46, 'West Virginia':-47, Wisconsin:-48, Wyoming:-49}),
        pop2: ({}),
        edi1: "",
        edi2: "SUBJECT",
        execDialog: function() { return app.execDialog(dialogDescriptor); },
        selectedItem: function (control) { if (typeof (control) === "string") { control = this[control]; } for (var item in control) { if (typeof (control[item]) === "object") { var r = this.selectedItem(control[item]);if (r !== undefined){ return r; }} else { if (control[item] > 0){return control[item];}}}}   };
    return dialogObject;
}
var d = dialog();
d.execDialog();
console.println(d.pop1.toSource());
console.println(d.pop2.toSource());
console.println(d.edi1);
console.println(d.edi2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the 'function dialog()'-Code in a sciptingobject
and rename the scriptingobject to 'Main'.

Then commented out:
`// var d = dialog();`
and
`// d.execDialog();`

Write in the Button-Click-Event:

```
var d = Main.dialog();
d.execDialog();
Textfield1.rawValue = d.edi1;
```

for the Index of the Dropdown pop1/pop2:
`Textfield2.rawValue =  d.selectedItem("pop1");`

I hope thats help a little bit...
Cleanman